# Не явное изменение значения переменной, Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему после столкновения переменная collis становится true, НО в следующем Update снова false? Ничего не понимаю, прошелся отладкой, нигде нет переприсваивания, да и эта переменная только в этой части кода присутствует

```
bool collis = false;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (collis == false)
    {
        this.transform.position += this.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else Debug.Log(collis);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    collis = true;
    Debug.Log(collis);
}
```

Тоесть из `Debug.Log` выполнение перескакивает на `Update` и там уже переменная `collis` равна `false`.

Comment: Как понял у тебя движется объект, как только столкнется с чем-то, должен остановиться?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ именно

Comment: Что-то странно, это весь код где используется переменная collis? Этот скрипт весит в единственном экземпляре на обьекте?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ вот и я в шоке, скрипт единственный, код также, весь что присутствует в скрипте, я даже переименовал переменную чтоб исключить совпадения, все равно тоже самое

Comment: попробуйте в чистом проекте без настроек, тупо 2 объекта и этот скрипт, должно все прекрасно работать